# Can't sudo while signed in with PuTTY, but can while using SSH from linux box

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, sudo, putty

I have found that when I am signed into my Arch Linux desktop via PuTTY I cannot use sudo, but if I SSH in from my linux laptop I can. I am currently using the workaround of attaching to a tmux session created while signed in on my laptop, but I would like to figure out the underlying cause.

Edit: The specific issue is that sudo says my password is incorrect, even though I have carefully typed it in one character at a time many times to double check.

Comment: Do you have characters in your password that are other than standard ASCII letters? E.g. things like `å`, or `é`, or letters prefixed by pressing `Alt` or `Ctrl`?

Comment: @Kusalananda : I’d bet you are right.

Comment: Could you answer the important question from @Kusalananda? Do you know the difference between alphabetical and ASCII characters?

Comment: Within your PuTTY session, could you enter: `/usr/bin/su $(whoami)` and report the result?

Answer (score 0):

Through your PuTTY connection fire the `cat` command
and simply type your password.
You will be able to see which of your password character is wrongly coded from your Windows environment. Most probably a special, control or meta character.

Comment: I've only got alphabetical characters in it. `cat` and `cat -T` didn't show anything weird.